# Inverse functions and derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

Suppose that $f:[a.b]\to[c,d]$ is differentiable and onto. If $f'$ is never 0 on $[a,b]$ and $d-c\geq2$, prove that for every $x\in[c,d]$, there exist $x_1\in[a,b]$ and $x_2\in[c,d]$ such that $|f'(x_1)(f^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(x_2))|=1$.

My attempt: We know $f:[a,b]\to[c,d]$ is differentiable and onto. Since $f'$ is never 0 on $[a,b]$, $$\vert f'(x_1)(f^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(x_2))\vert=1\Rightarrow\vert f^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(x_2)\vert=\frac{1}{\vert f'(x_1)\vert},$$ where $x,x_2\in[c,d]$ and $x_1\in[a,b]$. Since $f$ is onto, $\forall y_0\in[c,d],\exists x_0\in[a,b]:f(x_0)=y_0$. Say $f(x_1)=y_1$. Then if $f^{-1}$ is differentiable, $(f^{-1})'(y_1)=\frac{1}{f'(x_1)}$. By the mean value theorem, we know that for $x$ and $x_2$,
$$\bigg\vert\frac{ f^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(x_2)}{x-x_2}\bigg\vert=\vert(f^{-1})'(y_1)\vert$$ 
for some $y_1\in(x,x_2)$ or $(x_2,x)$. Now say $\vert x-x_2\vert=1$, so that $\vert f^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(x_2)\vert=\vert(f^{-1})'(y_1)\vert$. This means that $x_2=x\pm1$. Thus we have $$\vert f^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(x\pm1)\vert=\vert(f^{-1})'(x_1)\vert.$$ But $f(x_0)=y_0$ is only guaranteed by the mean value theorem if $y_0\in(x,x_2)$. 
And then I do not know where to go from here. I am pretty sure that I am not going about this the right way, but I am fairly certain that I should use the fact that $\vert f^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(x_2)\vert=\frac{1}{\vert f'(x_1)\vert}$, in addition to some other theorem guaranteeing the existence of points. How should I finish/correctly go about this proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea lacks structure but i think you actually proofed it already.

Let me try to sort your arguments:

Let $x \in [c,d]$. If $x$ is closer to $c$, set $x_2 = x + 1$, else if $x$ is closer to $d$ set $x_2 = x - 1$. In both cases $d-c\geq 2$ guarantees $x_2 \in[c,d]$ and you have $|x-x_2|=1$. By the mean value theorem there exists $y$ between $x$ and $x_2$ such that

$$|f^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(x_2)| = \left| \frac{f^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(x_2)}{x-x_2} \right| = |(f^{-1})'(y)| = \frac{1}{|f'(x_1)|}$$

where $f(x_1)=y$ and such an $x_1\in[a,b]$ exists because $f$ is onto. Note that you where able to use the inverse functions differentiation rule since $f'$ is never zero. Multiplying both sides of the equation with $|f'(x_1)|$ yields your desired result.

Again, i just repeated your arguments and sorted them a bit.